# Simple AsyncTask - Return value null

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have read into AsyncTask, I get most of it but I have still have a little question.

I basically want to use a thread to retrieve data from an online source, and return it to an activity. Below is a simple psuedo code.

```
public class register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public static String dbData;

     public static void setDBData(String data)
     {
         dbData = data;
     }

   //CALLED FROM ONCREATE()
 public void regPageTwo()
 {
     setContentView(R.layout.layout_register_two);
     new dataExchange().execute(1);
        Log.i("Data", dbData);

 }

}

public class dataExchange extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{

       @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
      //EVENTUALLY DO OTHER COMPUTATION
        String test="aTest";
        return test;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        register.setDBData(result);
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the poor formatting not quite use to using this yet). Any idea why dbData is always NULL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: new dataExchange().execute("");

Comment: it seems like you have problem with understanding code flow when you're usin async operation ... AsyncTask(as is stated in name of this class) is executed async ... so do not expect that value of `dbData` will be "aTest" just after you call `new dataExchange().execute(1);` (because execute will not wait until task is finished ... it just fire it) so put `Log.i("Data", dbData);` to `setDBData` after you set dbData ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void regPageTwo()
 {
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_register_two);
    new dataExchange().execute(1);
    Log.i("Data", dbData);
 }
```

After looking your above code,

the line `Log.i("Data", dbData);` should be in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask..

Actually, your code line `Log.i("Data", dbData);` immediately execute before complete of AsyncTask. so it always be a **NULL** You have to wait for complete AsyncTask. Or As I suggested put this line in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because this line will be executed:

```
Log.i("Data", dbData);
```

immediately after

```
new dataExchange().execute(1);
```

But this line will be executed at some time in the future:

```
register.setDBData(result);
```

This happens, because it runs **[asynchronously](http://www.bisque.com/help/CCDSoft/asynchronous_vs._synchronous_execution.htm)** on a different thread.